# C# Take operator

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Given the following declaration

```
int[] numbers = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
```

I notice that VS 2015 on .NET 4.6.1 allows the following to take the first three numbers

```
IEnumerable<int> firstThree = System.Linq.Enumerable.Take(numbers, 3);
```

However, it does not allow the following

```
IEnumerable<int> firstThree = numbers.Take(3);
```

I am new to C# and not able to understand why the call is not resolved to the extension method.

Comment: Last time I checked VS opens the following the namespaces for you automatically: `using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you miss to add

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Yes, that's the mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

[Take](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.100).aspx) is an extension method that you can find under the **namespace** `System.Linq`.

You simply need to include that namespace on your file:

```
using System.Linq;
```

and then you will be able to use the extension method.